# Prove that $ | a_0 | \leq \frac{2^n n^n}{n \cdot n! } $

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

Let $ P(x) = a_0 x^n + a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n $ be a polynomial with the following property :

$ |P(x)| \leq 1 $ for every $ x \in [0,1] $

Prove that

$$ | a_0 | \leq \frac{2^n n^n}{n \cdot n! } $$

I'm having some trouble proving this. I bet this one is solved using the divided difference of the polynomial, which is the coefficient of $ x^n$ $(a_0)$ :

$$ a_0 = [x_0,x_1,...,x_n;P] = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{P(x_i)}{l'(x_i)} $$

Comment: What are $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n$?  Are they related to $P(x)$?

Comment: Oh my bad, its was $ P(x) \leq 1 $

Comment: This problem is from interpolating polynomial lesson so $x_0, x_1 , ... , x_n $ are some distinct points from the interval

Comment: This doesn't seem correct.  This example $P(x)=-100x^2-100$ doesn't satisfy the condition, unless you meant $\big|P(x)\big|\leq 1$.

Comment: Indeed that was meant to be, just ugly handwriting :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chebyshev polynomials are defined by the recurrence:

$\begin{align*}
      T_0(x)
        &= 1 \\
      T_1(x)
        &= x \\
      T_{n + 1}(x)
        &= 2 x T_n(x) - T_{n - 1}(x)
          \quad n \ge 1
\end{align*}$

An explicit formula is:

$\begin{equation*}
  T_n(x)
    = \cos(n \arccos x)
\end{equation*}$

This can be proved by showing these polynomials satisfy the above recurrence. Note the recurrence implies $T_n(x) = 2^{n - 1} x^n + \dotsb$. By the explicit formula, $\lvert T_n(x) \rvert \le 1$ for $-1 \le x \le 1$.

**Theorem:** If $p(x)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n \ge 1$, then:

$\begin{align*}
  \max_{-1 \le x \le 1} \lvert p(x) \rvert
        &\ge 2^{1 - n}
\end{align*}$

**Proof:** By contradiction. Assume that for the monic polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n \ge 1$ for all $-1 \le x \le 1$ it is $\lvert p_n(x) \rvert < 2^{1 - n}$. Let $q(x) = 2^{1 - n} T_n(x)$, so $q$ is monic. Take the points $x_j = \cos (j \pi / n)$ for $0 \le j \le n$. By the explicit formula for Chebyshev polynomials, for those values $q(x_j) = (-1)^j \cdot 2^{1 - n}$. So $(-1)^j q(x_j) = 2^{1 - n}$. By our assumption on $p$, $(-1)^j p(x_j) \le \lvert p(x_j) \rvert < 2^{1 - n}  = (-1)^j q(x_j)$. So $(-1)^j (q(x_j) - p(x_j)) > 0$ for $x_0, \dotsc, x_n$ , i.e., the polynomial $q(x) - p(x)$ changes sign $n$ times in the interval. But as $p$ and $q$ are monic, $q(x) - p(x)$ is of degree $n - 1$, and can have at most $n - 1$ real zeros, contradiction.

Note this proves the bound $2^{1 - n}$ is best possible.